# Is it possible to pass an array of objects with request.query using Node.js and Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, request

I need to retrieve an array of objects like this (in Express):

```
[{product_id: 'aaabc26', quantity: 3}, {product_id: 'bbbad35', quantity: 8}]
```

Is it possible to do this in request.query? If so, what would the syntax for the request on the front-end look like?

Comment: Yeah, stringify it, base64 encode it, pass it as a query parameter. However, why don't you POST / UPDATE / ... instead and pass a proper json body?

Comment: It really makes more sense, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can convert array to string and add to query. This is not a good pratice, especially when the array get really large.